# Do I need to remove observer in NSObject?

Tags: ios, nsobject

I am still studying the foundation for Objective-C. I have written code like this in NSObject. Do I need to remove observer back? if so, where can I remove? I am using ARC. Do I need to remove in dealloc ?

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(preferredContentSizeChanged:)
         name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification
         object:nil];

    }
    return self; }
```

Answer (score 1):

**iOS 8 or earlier**
You need to unregister for this notification before deallocating the observer object. If you forget you are at risk of a crash.

**In OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.0 or later**

NSNotificationCenter and NSDistributedNotificationCenter will no longer send notifications to registered observers that may be deallocated.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000742

Comment: thanks. for ios 8 and below, do i just need to write this? 

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS 9+, you do not need to remove the observers that have been added. You can read more details about there here: [Unregistering NSNotificationCenter Observers in iOS 9](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/unregistering-nsnotificationcenter-observers-in-ios-9/)

Comment: thanks. for ios 8 and below, do i just need to write this? 

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}

Comment: You will, just need to remove self, it will remove all

Comment: What about keypath observers?